# changing variable value according to inputs created by select menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, for-loop, each

I need to pass input values to the db using ajax and php but have a problem storing values in a variable to pass it as a query string because I don't know how many inputs there will be. The needed code is inside `$("#addVote").click(function(){  });`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m55U4/

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="add_vote" style="width:300px; min-height:50px; max-height:100%;">
        <div class="question" style="width:210px; float:right;">
            <select id="Num">
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="answers" style="width:300px; float:right; min-height:30px; max-height:100%;"></div>
        <div class="add_vote" style="width:300px; float:right; min-height:30px; max-height:100%; text-align:center;">
            <input name="" type="button" id="addVote" value="save" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var num = $("#Num :selected").val();

    get_num();

    $(".answers").html('');
    var num = $("#Num :selected").val();
    for (var x = 1; x <= num; x++) {
        $(".answers").append('<input type="text" class="' + x + '">');
    }

    $("#addVote").click(function () {

    });

});

function get_num() {
    $("#Num").change(function () {
        $(".answers").html('');
        var num = $("#Num :selected").val();
        for (var x = 1; x <= num; x++) {
            $(".answers").append('<input type="text" class="' + x + '">');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize a form.

```
$('form').serialize()
```

You would have to give names to your inputs in order for the method to be able to generate the querystring.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Nqshy/)**